# How to Google OAuth Access Token in an iOs app using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, google-plus, google-oauth

I'm working on an iOS app where i need i use Google+ OAuth for login. I need to get the access token from the google server and send it to my server for authentication. There are many help on this using other languages but not for Objective C. Any help would be very helpful

Comment: Have you read _any_ of [this](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/)

Answer (score 0):

In the app delegate, implement the GIDSignInDelegate protocol to handle the sign-in process by defining the following methods:

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
  // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
  NSString *userId = user.userID;                  // For client-side use only!
  NSString *idToken = user.authentication.idToken; // Safe to send to the server
  NSString *name = user.profile.name;
  NSString *email = user.profile.email;
  // [START_EXCLUDE]
  NSDictionary *statusText = @{@"statusText":
                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Signed in user: %@",
                                  name]};
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   postNotificationName:@"ToggleAuthUINotification"
   object:nil
   userInfo:statusText];
  // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END signin_handler]
```

refer here [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/signin/SignInExample/AppDelegate.m)